# Javascript for loop in @section causes parser error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

When I use a JavaScript for loop inside the @section in MVC 4, I get a parser error that a curly brace } is expected. I've seen a few other posts about this (it was a known bug in Razor 2.0 before MVC4) but nothing that seems to address how to do this.

I'm not a JavaScript expert, so is there another way to declare and call this or something?

```
@section onReady{
var oTable;

    oTable = $('#services').dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 100,            
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "aoColumns": [
     { "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false },
     null, null, null, null, null, null ],

        "fnFooterCallback": function( nFoot, aData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay ) 
        {
            var iCalls = 0;
            for ( var i=0 ; i < aData.length ; i++ )
            {
                iCalls += aData[i][4]*1;
            }           
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I would guess one of the iterations of your loop doesn't have aData[i][4] actually set and thats whats breaking it.  You can wrap it in a if(typeof(aData[i][4]) !== "undefined"){...} to likely fix it.  You can verify contents of aData by console.log(aData) as well and checking it in console.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put section inside script tags. Instead, have such line in the layout page:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Then in the view:

```
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
        var oTable;
        //...
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `<script>` tags.

```
@section onReady{

<script type='text/javascript'>

$(function () {
    var oTable;

    oTable = $('#services').dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 100,
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "aoColumns": [{
            "bSortable": false,
            "bSearchable": false
        },
        null, null, null, null, null, null],

            "fnFooterCallback": function (nFoot, aData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {
            var iCalls = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < aData.length; i++) {
                iCalls += aData[i][4] * 1;
            }
        }
    });
}); 
</script>
}
```

Comment: That was helpful, but it made other stuff on that screen stop working in my DataTables stuff (the bulk of that is from others on the web and involved), from styles to functionality. I might need another approach even though you were right.

Comment: You definitely want to make sure you can limit the number of document.ready's. One is the best, so its centralized and you don't get any race conditions.